problem in creation of opensearch serverless collection while creating knowledge base in AWS
I have an issue in creating the knowledge base. When I create, it shows failed to create open search serverless collection.
Even though I gave the full access for bedrock and open search service for the user and the necessary permissions and made the s3 bucket to be accessed by the open search service, the issue is not fixed. I also defined collection related policies and permissions and assigned to the user. please help me to clear that issue 
